# Asking User for H

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

I want to ask the user (Using `Scanner`) how many times he wants the program to loop. I need to use the `do-while` loop statement to do this, but whenever I enter the number of times I want it to loop it only subtracts it from the value I put in while and repeats by that amount.

For example, I enter 4, the program repeats 16 times instead of 4 times.

Here is my program:

```
System.out.println("Enter range");
int y = input.nextInt();
int x = 10;
do {
    System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
    x++;
    y++;
    System.out.print("\n");
} while(y < 20);
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of y just after you do `int y = input.nextInt()` to ensure its value is the expected one?

Answer (score 5):

When you enter `4`, then `y` becomes `4` and the loop takes place until `y` reaches `20`. This is why it's executed 16 times.

If you want it to be executed exactly `y` times (in your case, `4`), then you can decrement `y` with `1` on each step until it reaches `0`.

```
System.out.println("Enter range");
int y = input.nextInt();
int x = 10;
do {
    System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
    x++;
    y--;
    System.out.print("\n");
} while(y > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked!! I'm so sorry for my programming skills im near total beginner 

How about if I want to ask the users midway in the loop if I want them to continue or not? If they decide to continue the program would continue looping with the initial value they entered and if not it would stop looping

Comment: Then you'll have to deal with `String` (terminating the loop once the user enters `"N"` or something like this)

Answer (score 3):

Change to `while(y-- > 0)` and don't `y++;` inside your loop. So it will become:

```
System.out.println("Enter range");
int y = input.nextInt();
int x = 10;
do {
    System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
    x++;
    System.out.print("\n");
} while(y-- > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawwed.

```
System.out.println("Enter range");
   int y = input.nextInt();
   int x = 10;
    do{
     System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
     x++;
     y++;
     System.out.print("\n");

   }while( y < 20  );
```

4 < 20 -> it loops, and each time, you increment with 1.
So: 5,6,7,8,...,19, they 'll all return true for y < 20

What you need to do, is compare a counter initiliazed at 0 against y:

```
System.out.println("Enter range");
   int y = input.nextInt();
   int x = 10;
   int count = 0;
    do{
     System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
     x++;
     count++;
     System.out.print("\n");

   }while( count < y  );
```